# Insert list elements inside another function in C

Tags: c, windows

Good Evening everyone, i have the code below where i am trying to add elements in a List and then display them. I use a Function called **smooth** where i find the average number between 9 numbers and then inside that function i use the **insert_at_beginning**  function to add them in the list and then i have the **display**  to print them.

While i am using the code from **smooth** function in to main(plain code) the programm works just fine. But when i am trying to make it work throught the **smooth** function i have no list to print. Which means that nothings adds up in my list.

Any Help would be much appriciated

Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M 6 
#define N 6 

struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next; 
    };

    typedef struct node LIST_NODE;//setting up aliases
    typedef struct node *LIST_PTR;
    struct node *head = NULL;
    
    void init_list(LIST_PTR *head)//arxikopisi tis listas
    {
        *head=NULL;
    }
    
    void free_list(LIST_PTR *head)//free memory of each node.
    {
        LIST_PTR ptr;//temporary pointer variable
        while(*head!=NULL)//while head is not empty(NULL)
        {
            ptr=*head;//set temporary as head
            *head=(*head)->next;//go to next
            free(ptr);//free memory
        }
    }
    
    void insert_at_beginning(LIST_PTR *head,float value) 
    {
        LIST_PTR newnode;// new node
        
        newnode=(LIST_NODE *)malloc(sizeof(LIST_NODE));//memory allocation forthe new node
        if(!newnode)//check if memory alocation has been successfull
        {
            printf("memory allocation failed");
    
        }
        newnode->data=value;//insert average value from smooth function
    
        newnode->next=*head;//set next of node to where head is pointing
        *head=newnode;//head will now point at new node
    
    }
    
    void display(LIST_PTR *head)
    {
        
       LIST_PTR current = *head;//temporary pointer variable as to where head is pointing
        
        while(current !=NULL)//while head is not empty(NULL)
        {
            printf("%d -> ",current->data);//print data
            current = current->next;//goto next node
            
        }
        if(current==NULL)
            printf("list empty");
      
    }
    
    void smooth(int K[M][N]) 
    {
    
    int q=0,h,i,j,l=0;
    int repi = 3;
    int repj = 3;
    float sum;
    float avg;
    /*test 1 */
    printf("\n-----------\n");
    
        for(h=0;h<(N-2)*(N-2);h++){
            sum = 0;
            avg = 0,0;
            for(i=q;i<repi;i++){
                for(j=l;j<repj;j++)
                {
                    printf("\t%d " ,K[i][j]);
                    sum+=K[i][j];
                    avg = round(sum/9);
                }
                printf("\n");   
            }
            insert_at_beginning(&head,avg);
            printf("-------%d---avg = %.0f------\n",h,avg);
            if(l<3){
                l++;
                repj++;     
            }
            else
            {
                l=0;
                q+=1;
                repi+=1;
                repj=3; 
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    int main(){ 
    
    system("chcp 1253>nul");
    
    int K[M][N]={60,68,61,63,59,61,156,161,162,159,156,158,162,159,170,163,165,166,234,255,157,234,211,244,245,232,225,253,200,205,67,66,58,65,66,71}; 
    int elem;
    int i,j,r=1;
    
    LIST_PTR head;
    init_list(&head);
    
    /*test array*/
    printf("K = [  ");
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("\t%d " ,K[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("]");
    
    smooth(K);
    
    display(&head);
    
    free_list(&head);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: And the debugger shows?

Comment: There are no issues , just the list is empty!

Comment: `system("chcp 1253>nul");` tells me this is Windows OS. Please update the tags.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Provide proper example.

Comment: I am using DEV C++, and it does compile make sure you add the libraries on top.

Comment: `error: ‘M’ undeclared here (not in a function)   63 |     void smooth(int K[M][N])`

Comment: Make sure **you** add proper minimal reproducable example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Sorry i had defined the 'M' and 'N'and forgot to write it on here. i just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables with the same name. The one `struct node *head = NULL;` is global. The other `LIST_PTR head;` is local to the main function. Look at where you place the variables and all will be clear.